# Triangular periodic tessellation in two variables

Tags: periodic-functions

The simple function $f(x, y) = \cos(x) + \cos(y)$ is doubly periodic in a square tessellation.   One feature of this surface is that cuts through the nearest extrema in either of two directions (e.g. $f(x,0)$ and $f(0,x)$) produce cosine curves.
A comparable function is $f(x,y) = \cos^{-1}(\cos(x)) + \cos^{-1}(\cos(y))$ where cuts produce triangle curves.

Is there a similar function $f$ $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that is doubly periodic in a triangular/hexagonal tessellation such that a cut through the nearest extrema in a row in any of three directions (e.g. $f(x,0)$, $f(x, \sqrt3x)$ and $f(-x, \sqrt3x)$) produces a sine or triangle curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and such a function is given directly by a linear transformation of your examples. A triangular/hexagonal lattice is just a special case of a two-dimensional lattice in which the lattice vectors form an angle of $\pi/3$, and any two-dimensional lattice can be obtained from a square lattice by a linear transformation. We merely have to check that a cut between next-to-nearest neighbours also produces sinusoidal curves, since the transformation transforms some of these into nearest neighbours. Indeed $f(x,x)=\cos x+\cos x=2\cos x$.

Now these curves aren't the same as the ones for nearest neighbours in the other two directions, $f(x,0)=\cos x +1$. If you want them to be the same, you can just add three rotated copies of this,

$$g(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^2\Omega^kTf(x,y)\;,$$

where $f$ is as in your examples, $T$ is an appropriate linear transformation (e.g. a skewing along the $x$ direction with an angle of $\pi/3$), and $\Omega$ is a rotation through $2\pi/3$ about the origin.

Here are [plots of that function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cos%20%28x%2by/2%29%20%2b%20cos%20%28y%29%20%2b%20cos%20%28c%20x%20%2b%20s%20y%20%2b%20%28c%20y%20-%20s%20x%29/2%29%20%2b%20cos%20%28c%20y%20-%20s%20x%29%20%2b%20cos%20%28c%20x%20-%20s%20y%20%2b%20%28c%20y%20%2b%20s%20x%29/2%29%20%2b%20cos%20%28c%20y%20%2b%20s%20x%29%20where%20c=%20-1/2,%20s%20=%20sqrt%283%29/2&incParTime=true). You can see in the contour plot that the symmetrization has made it more nearly rotationally symmetric near the origin than [your original function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cos%20%28x%29%20%2b%20cos%20%28y%29).

Comment: +1, but I can't resist pointing out that [the sum of three rotated copies of $\cos x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos%28x%29+%2B+cos%28cx%2Bsy%29+%2B+cos%28cx-sy%29+where+c+%3D+-1%2F2%2C+s+%3D+sqrt%283%29%2F2) also works.

Comment: @Rahul: Ah, of course -- in fact I strongly suspect that this is the same function up to a factor.